# How to use horizontal and vertical scrolling with server side processing in datatable jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, datatables

I am using 'Datatable Jquery plugin' with server side processing in my application. Now I want to use Horizontal and Vertical Scroll Bars in the datatable.

So to implement this, I used 'sScrollX', 'sScrollXInner' and 'sScrollY' in datatable code (as mentioned below) :

```
"sScrollX": "100%",
"sScrollXInner": "110%",
"sScrollY": 200,
```

after this, when I executed my application, the data did not come in datatable and an error occured in browser like "Object doesn't support this property or method" and it's indicating error in 'jquery.dataTables.js' JavaScript file.

Here I am sharing the URL of screenshots of datatable and error occurred respectively :

Below URL(Link) shows the datatable, where data didn't came and scrollbars also not showing in a proper way.

[Problematic dataTable screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s378/sh/f6545ba1-e13d-4c74-9601-3792359d4a72/d2a2db7469692312ebdb4d07fd94871b)

Below URL(Link) shows the error, which comes when datatable initialised.

[error occurred (screenshot)](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s378/sh/8a522ebb-77eb-43a2-a31c-d8ca767eaf00/8beec6f04df61be6babbca1c2ce6bd5b)

Below are the JavaScript and HTML Code what we are using in my application:

**JavaScript Code :**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    TableTools.BUTTONS.download = {
        "sAction": "text",
        "sTag": "default",
        "sFieldBoundary": "",
        "sFieldSeperator": "\t",
        "sNewLine": "<br>",
        "sToolTip": "Download Excel",
        "sButtonClass": "DTTT_button_xls", //eariler was "DTTT_button_text"
        "sButtonClassHover": "DTTT_button_xls_hover", //earlier was "DTTT_button_text_hover"
        "sButtonText": "Download",
        "mColumns": "all",
        "bHeader": true,
        "bFooter": true,
        "sDiv": "",
        "fnMouseover": null,
        "fnMouseout": null,
        "fnClick": function (nButton, oConfig) {
            var oParams = this.s.dt.oApi._fnAjaxParameters(this.s.dt);
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.height = "0px";
            iframe.style.width = "0px";
            iframe.src = oConfig.sUrl + "?" + $.param(oParams);
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        },
        "fnSelect": null,
        "fnComplete": null,
        "fnInit": null
    };
    $('#id_submit').click(function () {
        $("#prepack").dataTable({
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bRetrieve": false,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/demo_trial_application/DatasourceGsonServlet",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": "110%",
            "sScrollY": 200,
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "aButtons": ["copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf"],
                "sSwfPath": "./table_tool2.0/media/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
            },
            "aaSorting": [
                [0, 'desc']
            ]
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML Code :**

```
<body>


<input type="button" id="id_submit" name="txt_submit" value="Submit.." style="height: 24px; ">

<br>

<div id="div_prepack" >

    <table id="prepack" class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width: 2px; border-style: ridge; width: 1000px;">
        <thead>
                        <tr>
            <th>Site_id</th>
            <th>Low_ord_srl_no</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>Pass Flag</th>
            <th>Emp_no</th>
            <th>Last Update </th>
            <th>ETL_batch_id </th>
        </tr>    
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7"><span style="color: red;">Loading Data From Server...</span>   </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>

</div>
```

Please tell me if anything wrong in above mentioned code. I am getting error (as mentioned) at the time of server side processing, hence scroll bars are not showing and data are also not coming.

Answer (score 0):

try:

"sScrollY": "100%"

or

"sScrollY": "200px".

Do you still get the error?